# PostgreSQL: Select the group with specific members

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

Given the tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE group_members (
    group_id bigint REFERENCES groups ON DELETE CASCADE,
    user_id bigint REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id, user_id)
);
```

How do we select a group with a specific set of users?

We want an SQL function that takes an array of user IDs and returns the group ID (from the `group_members` table) with the exact same set of user IDs.

Also, please add indexes if they will make your solution faster.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to get "candidate" rows from `group_members` relation, and then with additional run ensure that group size is the same as user_ids array size (here I use CTE https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with target(id) as (
  select * from unnest(array[2, 3])          -- here is your input
), candidates as (
  select group_id
  from group_members
  where user_id in (select id from target)   -- find all groups which include input
)
select group_id
from group_members
where group_id in (select group_id from candidates)
group by group_id
having array_length(array_agg(user_id), 1) 
  = array_length(array(select id from target), 1) -- filter out all "bigger" groups
;
```

Demonstration with some sample data: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a98c09f20e837dc430ac66e01c7f0dd0

This query will utilize indexes you already have, but probably it's worth to add a separate index on `group_members (user_id)` to avoid intermediate hashing in the first stage of the CTE query.

SQL function is straightforward:

```
create or replace function find_groups(int8[]) returns int8 as $$
  with candidates as (
    select group_id
    from group_members
    where user_id in (select * from unnest($1))
  )
  select group_id
  from group_members
  where group_id in (select group_id from candidates)
  group by group_id
  having array_length(array_agg(user_id), 1) = array_length($1, 1)
  ;
$$ language sql;
```

See the same DBfiddle for demonstration.

Comment: Thank you, Nick! :-) Would it be faster (and still correct) to change `where user_id in (select * from unnest($1))` to `where user_id = $1[1]`?

Comment: Using `[1]` would change semantics. What would be correct here is `array[user_id] <@ $1` but I doubt that this will be faster. (The index won't be used)

Comment: Oh there is another way as well, `user_id = ANY($1)`. But I also doubt that it will be at least something faster.

Comment: Yes, using `[1]` would change the semantics, but would it change the correctness?

Comment: Not sure, what is your question about. If you take only the 1st element of the array, you will potentially take groups of the same size, but with different members. So the query will be wrong.

Comment: Oh, right. I'm sorry. By "correctness," I actually meant "functionality." I mistakenly assumed the query already worked correctly.